# Twitter Fabric freezes and crashes in genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion, twitter-fabric

I installed twitter- fabric plugin on Android Studio. I added it to my project. But I run my application in genymotion after a while , it freezes and crashes. It works normally in my real smartphone.  How can i solve it ?

**Main.java**

```
Fabric.with(context, new Crashlytics());
```

**Game.java**

```
Answers Answers = new Answers();
        LevelStartEvent a = new LevelStartEvent();
        Answers.getInstance().logLevelStart(a
                .putLevelName(getLevel()));
```

Comment: You don't provide code so very hard to understand what the issue is. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you to rephrase your question so that you will get the potential answer.

Comment: I didn't use code. Fabric works background asycn with its libraries. It only added this code : " Fabric.with(context, new Crashlytics());"  to my launcher activity

Comment: Actually it did more than that, also in manifest and gradle file. Put the stack trace at least.